# Django server hangs sometimes

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am new to Django and I run into strange problem that the server hangs sometimes.

The server uses `APScheduler` to do periodic tasks and send data to frontend via WebSocket. So, after the server freezes, I pressed CRTL+C to perform keyboard Interrupt. The server became normal again.

I run the server in debug mode locally on my machine. But this problem only happens once or twice for the past two weeks. The rest of time it runs normally.

The first time it happened when I tried to login.

```
Application instance \<Task pending name='Task-1119' coro=\<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at D:\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\channels\\staticfiles.py:44\> wait_for.\<Future pending cb=\[\_chain_future.\<locals\>.\_call_check_cancel() at D:\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\asyncio\\futures.py:385, Task.task_wakeup()\]\>\> for connection \<WebRequest at Ox25f4bObad70 method=POST uri=/admin/login/ clientproto=HTTP/1.1\> took too long to shut down and was killed
```

The second time it happened when I tried to visit `taskManager` page.

```
Application instance \<Task pending name='Task-153' coro=\<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at D:\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\channels\\staticfiles.py:44\> wait_for.\<Future pending cb=\[\_chain_future.\<locals\>.\_call_check_cancel() at D:\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\asyncio\\futures.py:385, Task.task_wakeup()\]\>\> for connection \<WebRequest at Ox19fbb5140550 method=POST uri=/taskManager clientproto=HTTP/1.1\> took too long to shut down and was killed
```

Python: 3.10.7

Django: 3.2

Channel: 3.0.5 And I am using `InMemoryChannelLayer`

I am not sure if it jammed when trying to response GET or POST, or the server jammed first so it cannot process any request.

I tried to google this problem. It seems that other developers may have the similar problem because of WebSocket. I added some msg to be printed before any `WebSocketConsumer` function called. But I did not see any related ones in the cmd.

I am really confusing now. Since I cannot replicate the problem. Can anyone give me some suggestions about how to debug this problem?

Comment: I guess , you faced the issue in django development server, the Django development server, a lightweight web server, not some thing for production, check whether same is happening in production.

Comment: Windows users using cmd to run the server: If you click on the console, it stops the execution of the server and you have to press ENTER on the cmd so the server continue execution.